# Mercurial, ask for the password only once

Tags: mercurial

My problem is the next one:
I work with several remote repos with Mercurial.
Every time I want to pull and update from the remote repos I write

```
hg pull -u
```

Once I introduce this command, I am asked for the password for every repo.
Is there a way to automate this behaviour in order to enter the password only once?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Mercurial Keyring](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeyringExtension) extension, which is distributed with TortoiseHg.